# Mysql using alias for localhost

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to 'fake' our development server into thinking the three production db servers I have are on localhost. I have set the following into hosts...

```
127.0.0.1      localhost dev1 dev2 dev3
```

I set up a user in Mysql with localhost as the host and everything works fine. If I change to the dev1 user and restart privileges, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dev1' (4)'
>   in /var/www/config/lib.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/config/lib.php(11): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=dev1',
>   'user', 'password', Array) #1

The exact same connection works as localhost, not as dev1. Why is this? I am running `Mysql 5.7.` I also tried using just `127.0.0.1` and that didn't work either.

Before you flag me as duplicate, I did check

[Using an alias for the localhost server in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466320/using-an-alias-for-the-localhost-server-in-mysql)

And that solution does not apply for me because I know I accept connections on `port 3306` from our other dev servers. But is it possible that a similar issue exists relating to a non-localhost hostname and default port use? Do I have to open the port for localhost in my firewall?

The main reason I am trying to do this is so that that my code doesn't have to change from dev to production. I have three **DB** servers but all are using the same one on localhost for dev.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Well, the issue is explained well in the other answer: `localhost` is a special keyword to the client which triggers entirely different behaviour than *anything else*. What you're doing is equivalent to connecting to `127.0.0.1`, and as you say, that doesn't work. Make that work in your MySQL server configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an alias for the localhost server in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466320/using-an-alias-for-the-localhost-server-in-mysql)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate, That user did not have Mysql open for external access. I do. His solution was to enable mysql for external access and that does not solve my problem. Instead of being so concerned about duplicates before reading and reformatting, maybe try to answer the question?

Comment: @deceze - I did. I tried to run everything off of 127.0.0.1, including setting the mysql user host. Also opened that in firewall for port 3306. I wonder if it is best to just use the external IP address for DB connections, even on the local machine.